# Squat getting strong but legs don't grow

Tags: bodybuilding, squats

I'm a 19 years old boy and this week my one rep max front-squat improved from 72.5 kilograms to 85 kilograms but legs  didn't grow in width at all.

Is the process slower than i though or am I doing something wrong? Consider my diet consist of 4574 calories every day of the week...

Comment: How many reps and sets do you do? Wait longer and if it's still not working, try to add more volume (reps, sets and weight) per session. Also Front Squat targets legs well but you may be limited by your upper back. Try Back squatting.

Comment: How long have you been squatting for?

Comment: 3 weeks since I  first started and i do 5x7

Comment: What are your current bodyweight and height?  How many grams of protein do you consume per day?  Why are you doing so many sets and reps?  Why aren't you back-squatting?

Comment: Well, since you are squatting since 3 weeks and expected your legs to noticeably grow I might have some bad news for you. Of course, now is the time for most progress in strength and size, but just give it some time. Keep squatting 2-3 times a week and you'll grow bigger. No doubt about it. (As long as you eat a healthy amount of calories and proteins).

Comment: 121 grams of protein

Comment: Come back with before & after measurements after squatting consistently for at least 6 months. If you haven't grown at all during that time then something may be limiting you (programming/diet).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you've been only working out for 3 weeks. I suggest you take some pictures or measure your legs right now.

After measuring, be consistent in your training, eating and rest periods for the next 6 months. I see that you're eating over 4000 calories and 120+ grams of protein a day, this should give you ample fule to grow.

After 6 months, measure again and I'm without a doubt sure that you will have gained mass on your legs.

Answer (score 0):

For hypertrophy go for higher number of reps. Low reps high weight definitely build strength and some size, but if you're aiming for size, you'll want to lower the weight a bit, and hit higher reps.

Also, are you doing anything else for legs? Romanian deadlifts (absolutely killer for hamstrings), deadlifts, leg press, extensions, reverse hypers etc. All those stimulate different muscles and adjusting rep ranges towards 8+ will definitely result in size.

For measurements, you'll want to measure every week or two, in the same areas around the same time. Water intake, time of the day etc. can all affect measurements.

Either way, if you're gaining strength, keep at it. It's not like you'll see a lot of progress in one week. It's a marathon. Experiment with the rep ranges and have fun. It's like experimenting on your own body!